# CakePHP friendship

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables users and friendships and I've created the model and the Friendshipscontroller but once I try to "add" a friend a get an error that i'm missing "add_friend" view.

Here is my add_friend function from the Friendshipscontroller

```
function add_friend ( $id ){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $this->Friendship->Create();
        if($this->Friendship->save($this->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Friendship Requested');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'profile'));
        }
    }
```

And this is how I reference to it in my view

```
<?php echo 
$this->Html->link('Add as Friend', array('controller' => 'Friendships', 'action'=>'add_friend', h($user['User']['id'])));
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so I don't know where to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

This first line in your method:

```
if(!empty($this->data)){
```

is being evaluated as "false" as there's no data in $this->data. Therefore, nothing else is executed on that method, and standard cakePHP flow continues. That means, rendering the view.

Obviously, as $this->data is empty, majority of the code of your method is "wrong". Friendship between who and who? 
Assuming you are already dealing with Auth, and the relation between Friendship and User, something like this would work:

```
function add_friend ( $id ){
if(!empty($id) && $this->Friendship->User->exists($id)){
    $this->Friendship->create();
    if($this->Friendship->save(array('user_id' => $id, 'requesteduser_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')))){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Friendship Requested');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'profile'));
    }
}
```

}

Hope it helps!

Comment: Error: Call to a member function exists() on a non-object. I've used exists() before and there was no problem. Could it be that I'm writing something wrong here?

Comment: Your error (probably) is due you didn't set a relation between Friendship and User.

When giving you the answer I was assuming that:
1. You are using cakephp v2.x
2. The method add_friend was in FriendshipsController
3. A relation was set between Friendship and User (belongsTo)
4. You are already using Auth for Authentication purposes.

If you don't clearly understand any of the points above, I would recommend you to take a deeper look to cakephp documentation and its tutorials: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html